# done dont works with scenario in jasminejs

Tags: javascript, testing

first, I really love the new version of jasmine, its very easy and human with the enhacements,
but I have the problem with testing this escenario in my Spec:

https://github.com/yosonjs/yosonjs/blob/master/test/spec/SpecCore.js#L30

I put the "x" because i don't want error when travis-ci execute
The basic funcionality of the library depuring it works here if you put an browser the little demo:
https://github.com/yosonjs/yosonjs/blob/master/examples/debug-area/welcome.html

I think by the scope of the function but its a escenario very especial.
Note: the steps of have the escenario you can follow here:
https://github.com/yosonjs/yosonjs/blob/master/DEVELOPMENT.md

Answer (score 0):

My apologies of this issue, now it works! I solved the spec, and here the solution:
https://github.com/yosonjs/yosonjs/blob/master/test/spec/SpecCore.js#L28

The error was when I declare an module empty, and create a new module with the same name, but it solved :)